# mysql select distinct but latest row

Tags: mysql, sql

How can I select the latest 'score' from a table for each distinct 'site' that exists?

For example:

```
site |   date   | score
 a   | 20140101 |  10
 a   | 20140102 |  8
 b   | 20140103 |  11
 b   | 20140202 |  9
```

I'd like to return one result for `a` and `b`, but only their latest entry (by date).

```
 a   | 20140102 |  8
 b   | 20140202 |  9
```

I know how to group by site, or select distinct site, but not sure how to narrow it down to their latest dates.

edit: this should be dynamic for thousands of distinct sites.

Comment: Do you have primary key, say 'id', for your table?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it with a union

```
(SELECT 
    site,date,score 
FROM
    `table`
WHERE 
    site = 'a'
ORDER BY date DESC
LIMIT 0,1)
UNION
(SELECT 
    site,date,score 
FROM
    `table`
WHERE 
    site = 'b'
ORDER BY date DESC
LIMIT 0,1)
```

A little more convoluted if you don't want to write a `UNION`

```
SELECT 
    t.site, t.date, t.score
FROM 
    `table` t
    JOIN (
       SELECT ti.site,MAX(ti.date) AS dt
       FROM `table` ti
       GROUP BY ti.site
    ) t2 ON t2.site = t.site and t2.dt = t.date
```

Comment: thanks, there will be thousands of rows though, so looking for something more dynamic

Comment: +1 .... you need to use alias use alias otherwise error 1052: Column 'site' in field list is ambiguous.. SELECT t.site ..

Comment: @mhasan thanks - I updated the query to reflect that.

Comment: thanks! I'm pretty sure this is working as expected now!